# how to split a string between 2 parametres in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, macos, split, multiparameter

Hi I try to separate input like this : `<Text1><Text2><Text2>..<TextN>`
in a array who only have each text in each index, how I can use split with double parameters?
I try  make a double split but doesn't work:

```
request = client.gets.chomp
dev = request.split("<")
split_doble(dev)

dev.each do |devo|
  puts devo
end 

def split_doble (str1)
  str1.each do |str2|
    str2.split(">")
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example input and the expected output?

Comment: thanks for the edit!! I have an input like this: <text1><text2>...<textN> and I need  work with each text for separate so I think maybe I can use some split who allowed separate each text between two parameters as I told before

Answer (score 1):

When you have a string like this

```
string = "<text1><text2><textN>"
```

then you can extract the text between the `<` and `>` chars like that:

```
string.scan(/\w+/)
#=> ["text1", "text2", "textN"]
```

`/\w+/` is a regular expression that matches a sequence of word characters (letter, number, underscore) and therefore ignores the `<` and `>` characters.

Also see docs about [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Answer (score 0):

In the string `"<text1><text2><textN>"` the leading < and ending > are in the way, so get rid of them by slicing them off. Then just split on "><".

```
str = "<text1><text2><textN>"
p str[1..-2].split("><") # => ["text1", "text2", "textN"]
```